# HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode() never returns HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK in my android code, but the same thing works in Java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get some XML data from the web from within my android app, I have made the task run using AsyncTask, but when i get to this code in my XMMLParser it does not run:

```
if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
```

And the surrounding code for reference:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1"
                + "/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo"
                + ".finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20"
                + "(%22MSFT%22)&diagnostics=true&env=store"
                + "%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        Log.d("PROGRESS", "Checking HTTP Connection");
        if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    //Get XML Data
                    }
     }catch(Exception e){
     }
```

I have run this exact code in a Java project and it works flawlessly. The permissions have already been set to allow internet in the AndroidManifest.xml, I'm unsure where to go from here.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Checked the response code in the debugger, it is -1.

Comment: What does it return on android?

Comment: The responseCode is -1

Comment: Have you tried to create a separate Android app which only executes this AsyncTask from its main activity? Because according to the current description there is nothing wrong, but may be there is something else in your current application which we do not know. I would have tried also using `HttpClient` but this is only after trying your current issue as a separate application. Also I assume that you do not have any proxy for Internet connection.